# How can I display custom post type grouped by a "select" cutom field value?

Tags: loop, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type. I use ACF for the layout of this custom post type. In ACF, the field is called "temoignage_category", the field type is a "select" and in the "choices" field there are 4 different options. In the edit page of each custom post type, I select one of the 4 options

What I want is to **display these 4 options as section titles, then under each of them display the corresponding custom post type**

For example :
My custom field value 1

- post 1
- post 2
- post 3

My custom field Value 2

- post 4
- post 5
- post 6

etc..

```
$temoignage_category = get_field('temoignage_category');
        $args = array(
                'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                'post_type'     => 'temoignage',
                'meta_key' => 'temoignage_category',
                'meta_value' => $temoignage_category,
                'orderby'           => 'meta_value'
                
);
                
         
          $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
          echo "<div class='temoignagerow'>";
          if( $the_query->have_posts() ): 
            
            if( $temoignage_category ) { echo '<h2>'.$temoignage_category.'</h2>'; };
            
          while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

          $color = get_field('background_color', get_field('chapitre', $value->ID)->ID); ?>
          <a class="temoignagecard " style="border-color: <?= $color ?>; color: <?= $color ?>"
             href="<?= get_permalink($value->ID) ?>">
            <div class="inner archive_inner">
              <img src="<?= get_field("photo", $value->ID)['url'] ?>" alt="">
              <p><?= get_the_title($value->ID) ?></p>
            </div>
          </a>
       <?php  
      endwhile;
      endif;
      echo '</div>';
      wp_reset_query();
     ?>
```

This loop just allows me to display the custom post types in order, but it does not display the custom field with the corresponding custom post types below.

I know you have to nest the loops, but all I can do for now is display the custom post type. could someone tell me how to proceed?